# Shiny renderUI not Selectinput stopped updating on its own

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

I am a newbie in Shiny. I am working on a dashboard. I am using renderUI to get some input. For 2 days, the code was working fine but suddenly today it started giving me issues. Any help would be much appreciated.

ui code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
column(width =6,
       box(width = NULL, status = "warning",solidHeader = TRUE,
            title = "Topics Level",
            selectInput(inputId = "Vis_level_select", 
                        label = "",
                        selected = "Main Topics",
                        choices = c("Main Topics","Sub-Topics")
                       )
                   )
            ),

## Topic Number Output
column(width = 6,
       box(width = NULL, status = "warning",solidHeader = TRUE,
           title = "Select the topic for which Sub Topics are to be shown",
           uiOutput("topic_no_select")
           )
      ))
```

server code:

```
server <- function(input, output){
## Topic number output
output$topic_no_select <- renderUI({
  if(input$Vis_level_select == "Main Topics"){
  selectInput(inputId = "main_topic_no", label = "", choices = "N/A", selected = "N/A")
} else{
  selectInput(inputId = "main_topic_no", label = "", choices = c(1:10), selected = 1)
}
})

## LDAvis output
output$LDAvis_output <- renderVis({
  if(input$Vis_level_select == "Sub-Topics"){
  viz_file <- paste0("Viz_Sub_topics_Main_Topic_",input$main_topic_no)
} else if(input$Vis_level_select == "Main Topics"){
  viz_file <- "Viz_Sub_topics_Main_Topics"
}
  get(viz_file)
})
}
```

The if statement in `LDAvis` output gives me blank and it gives me an error saying that `Viz_Sub_topics_Main_Topic_` not found. Once I change the value of `input$Vis_level_select` then the first part of `LDAvis` works but still the second part is not working. I am unable to understand why this is happening.

Please let me know if this is just a bug that will go away on restarting.

Comment: See `?get`, I think you need `return` not `get`

Comment: So what is your `Viz_Sub_topics_Main_Topics` variable in your app?

Comment: And where is your ui correspond to `output$LDAvis_output` ?

Comment: @A.Suliman `return` will return the string. I am passing the name of the object into `get` to get the output.
@JimChen `Viz_Sub_topics_Main_Topics` is the name of json string that is an input for LDAvis. Request you to refer to LDAvis documentation for more info. 

The issue is not related to LDAvis. It is related to renderUI in which the selectInput inside if statement is not working even though the condition is True.